# three js texture with webGL

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, webgl

If load an texture to an object that I load in threeJS with webGL, I do get the following error :

Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Chosen format/type incured an expensive reformat: 0x1908/0x1401

Does somebody knows why this is?

Code for uploading texture below :

```
  var loaderA = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
  loaderA.load('hout.jpg', function ( image ) {

  texture.image = image;
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  } );


  var loaderB = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

  loaderB.load('hoesjes/iphone.obj', function ( object ) {

  object.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

        //Changing color
        //texture = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x686876 } );
        //color.needsUpdate = true;

        //texture
        child.material.map = texture;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;

    }

} );
```

Comment: Firefox, right?

Comment: This is similar to [the question LJ linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251254/avoid-cpu-side-conversion-with-teximage2d-in-firefox) but that question is about WebGL. This question is about Three.js so if there is a solution the answers would be different.