# How's texImage2D from array different from that from canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

when I sample a pure block of color:

```
contentGL.readPixels(0, 0, contentGL.drawingBufferWidth, contentGL.drawingBufferHeight, contentGL.RGBA, contentGL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

the code above generates the correct result, however, the code below:

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, contentGL.canvas);
```

result in a slightly different color.
What may be the cause for that? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251254/avoid-cpu-side-conversion-with-teximage2d-in-firefox the premultiplied alpha issue.

Comment: If you want to copy the WebGL canvas into a texture see `copyTexImage2D`. Copying the canvas into a texture tho seems like it's rarely the right thing to do. Usually people render into texture directly by attaching it to a framebuffer.

Comment: Thank you. I was just using canvas as a quick and dirty temp fix, will change them into framebuffer eventually.